# setVisibility & setProgress not perform their jobs

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm facing two issues in android

1-I'm getting confused about what I'm trying to `setVisibility` of an `ImageView`programatically but it not work.

here is my XML code

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selfie_capture_image"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/captured_image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

and in runtime I use

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I've googled it and some solutions was to run it on UI thread & post & view.requestLayout but all of them not work for me

2- I'm trying to set progress for a seekbar on runtime but not working too.
this is my XML code

```
<SeekBar
       android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:visibility="invisible" />
```

here is what I need to do and getting error

```
maxValue *= 0.1f;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
   seekBar.setProgress(maxValue , true);
else
   seekBar.setProgress(maxValue);
});
```

Comment: Please explain what "not working" means in your cases.

Comment: Instead of saying it is not working, you should rather say what happens. Also some code by editing your question...show us where the problem happens...

Comment: @laalto I mean they not doing their job >> imageviwe not displayed and thumb of seekbar not moved wen use setProgress.

Comment: Instead of saying it is not working, you should rather say what happens. Also some code by editing your question...show us where the problem happens...

Comment: @Xenolion I did some modification please check

Comment: @Xenolion I need to make seekbar at 10% of its max that is calculated by some equation and even if I moved it some 40 or 50 not move too.

Comment: Do you need a Seekbar or a ProgressBar can I ask?

Comment: seekbar as I mentioned in the example.